# Json.net not reading back primary key

Tags: vb.net, json.net, csla

I'm using Newsoft JSON lib in a vb .net project and I found this error I can't solve.

[image: PK Problem]

I use CLSA objects of type **Formulario** and add some to a list. When I serialize that list the Primary Keys value are fine. In this example the first object of the list has a value of 3 in the ID property but after deserialize the object that value returns 0.

This happend with every ID. I check CSLA class and try to tweak some values like Int32 to Integer or change the readonly property to a read/write property but no avail.

Am I missing something? Every other property has the correct value but the IDs.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you share a [minimal but complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem that we could use to test and debug the problem?  Without being able to see the `Formulario` class it's unlikely we will be able to help.

Comment: You'll need to add more details as dbc says, but if you're deserializing into your Csla object from JSON you'll need to make the ID property publically settable, or I think Newsoft won't try to set it.